# Failed to edit torrc file

Tags: configuration

I tried to change the torrc file (on the Windows 8.1) but when I want to launch Tor I get this screen below. I want to use Stem library so I wrote this text in torrc:
`HashedControlPassword ***
SocksPort 9150 IPv6Traffic PreferIPv6 KeepAliveIsolateSOCKSAuth
ControlPort 9151
CookieAuthentication 1`
[image: torrc editing failure]

Comment: Does your torrc have line breaks? Can you access the log file?